# Where can I download gd2 extension for PHP5.5 and how to install it

Tags: php

I met the question from work.
Web developer wants me to install gd2 extension and xmlrpc extension for PHP5.5 in Ubuntu 12.04 which is a running web-server for add new function for new web.

I tried it and I can install xmlrpc extension successfully but I can't install gd2 by using apt-get install. So I wonder where can I download gd2 extension for PHP5.5 and how to install it from the download?

Thanks,

Detail shows in below pictures:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, the PHP `gd2` extension is provided by the [`php5-gd`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5) package, that's what you need to install.

While I'm at it, I think you need to check the repositories you're using: there's a not-so-hidden message in the version number of the `php5-xmlrpc` package you've installed...

Comment: Hi Stephen,

Thank you for your reply.
Do you know how to check repositories in Ubuntu 12.04? 
Also by checking the version of xmlrpc is xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51.

Comment: Note that I mentioned `php5-xmlrpc`, not `xmlrpc-epi`; the version of `php5-xmlrpc` you have installed is "5.5.37+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org-precise+1". To check what repositories you're using you need to look in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any file in `/etc/apt/sources.list/*.list`, and determine which ones are appropriate...

Comment: I think maybe the issue locates in the repositories. How to test if the repository is OK or not? 

Below is the some content in /etc/apt/sources.list:

**24 deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
 25 deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
 26 deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
 27 deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on php 7 like me try this php 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

Try this for php 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```